# DateTimePicker css incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using DateTimePicker on a c# MVC application to show date and time. The problem I am having is that the DateTimePicker not displaying date or time. I think it's a problem with the CSS but I'm not sure. Here is the code for the DateTimePicker (HTML):

```html
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <br />
            <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
            <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" type='text' class="form-control" id='start' />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```js
    $("#start").datetimepicker({
        format: dateF
    });
    $('#start').on('dp.change', function (e) {
        $('#end').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
```

And this is what it looks like when I press on it:

[image]

I am bundling the scripts like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/picker").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
                    ));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                "~/Content/layout.css",
                "~/Content/Style.css",
                "~/Content/tether.min.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
                ));
```

And rendering like this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/picker")
```

Any ideas about why this isn't working?

Comment: Checked the browser network tab for any errors (404) if the files aren't in the place you've specified (or 403 can't read them there for some reason) ?

Comment: all the required scripts are there (bootsrap, jquery, datepicker/datetimepicker) and loaded

Comment: Whats is `dateF`?  A formatting function? can you post that?

Comment: `dateF` is a formatting cookie, it just changes the order of year month and day

Comment: you say that you think the problem is with your CSS, so please post the relevant CSS.

Comment: I mean the linking of css. The css file is the default file that comes with the script. I show how I link it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the input type to 'date'

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <br />
        <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
        <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" type='date' class="form-control" id='start' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This gives me the option the click up and down to change the date, not the calendar view/time view I'm looking for.

Comment: There is a `jquery` error, but I'm using `jquery-3.3.1` which is loaded, could this be the problem?

Comment: may be. if you can post a screenshot or what ever that error is. It would be more helpful